# Tabs in AngularJS (v1.5.5)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, angularjs-material

I tried to achieve that using Angular-material (last version 1.1.8), but I am getting the following error:

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $mdUtilProvider <- $mdUtil <- layoutDirective <- $mdTheming

The code is here:

https://codepen.io/mrfabio/pen/QrLxNE

```
  <div class="sample tabsdemoDynamicTabs" layout="column" ng-cloak="">
    <md-content class="md-padding">
      <md-tabs md-selected="selectedIndex" md-border-bottom="" md-autoselect="" md-swipe-content="">
        <md-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-disabled="tab.disabled" label="{{tab.title}}">
          <div class="demo-tab tab{{$index%4}}" style="padding: 25px; text-align: center;">
            <div ng-bind="tab.content"></div>
            <br>
            <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="removeTab( tab )" ng-disabled="tabs.length <= 1">Remove Tab</md-button>
          </div>
        </md-tab>
      </md-tabs>
    </md-content>

    <form ng-submit="addTab(tTitle,tContent)" layout="column" class="md-padding" style="padding-top: 0;">
      <div layout="row" layout-sm="column">
        <div flex="" style="position: relative;">
          <h2 class="md-subhead" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; margin: 0; font-weight: 500; text-transform: uppercase; line-height: 35px; white-space: nowrap;">Add a new Tab:</h2>
        </div>
        <md-input-container>
          <label for="label">Label</label>
          <input type="text" id="label" ng-model="tTitle">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
          <label for="content">Content</label>
          <input type="text" id="content" ng-model="tContent">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-button class="add-tab md-primary md-raised" ng-disabled="!tTitle || !tContent" type="submit" style="margin-right: 0;">Add Tab</md-button>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
```

from: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs

I am including both JS and CSS, any idea about where the problem could be or if I can use a different approach? My goal is to represent components on different tabs, and be able to close or open new ones...

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't seem to be getting the error on your codepen.

Comment: I am integrating the code in a platform. I am using AngularJs 1.5, is it compatible with Angular material 1.1.8? Do you know any alternatives to this approach to present components on different tabs in the same page? Thanks in advance